# Web crawler to compare two versions of the same website

Tags: web-development, web-browser, web

Is there some software to compare two versions of the same website. I need to compare html source of ALL the pages of two websites, in order to quickly sort out the differences between the two and eventually fix them.

This would be helpful to mantain an up to date website in preproduction with the one available in production.

Comment: Just be aware of dynamically generated content, such as copyright dates, banner ads, and more